# SetActiveSheet() no longer working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet I built to be used as a template for my company. We have been using said template for the past 6 months without a hitch until yesterday. I have a script that takes you to different tabs within the spreadsheet it has been working great until yesterday.

When I run the debugger on the goToSheet() function, I get this error message:

"We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 3, file "goTo")Dismiss"

Did something change within google, or is there maybe a better way to go about this?

The following script is tied to a few buttons throughout the template as well as called on in a few other scripts.

```
function goToSheet(sheetName) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet);
}

function GotoPO2(){
  goToSheet('PO2');
} 
function GotoSpecialHandlingRequest(){
  goToSheet('Special Handling Request');
} 
function GotoProof(){
  goToSheet('Proof');
}
function GotoRFQ(){
  goToSheet('RFQ');
} 
function GotoBudget(){
  goToSheet('Budgt-Recnle_A');
}
function GotoPostagePO(){
  goToSheet('Postage PO');
}
function GotoPOCont(){
  goToSheet('PO Cont.');
}
function GotoPOCont2(){
  goToSheet('PO Cont.2');
}
function GotoVersion1(){
  goToSheet('Version 1 ');
}
```

Thank you any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up finding the answer myself, this is a known issue as you can see [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5519&thanks=5519&ts=1447287538)

The issue is the setActiveSheet().

A work around I found via the above link, I was able to adapt to my script with success by replacing `SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet);` with `sheet.getRange("A1").activate();`

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that `setActiveSheet()` doesn't work if you run it from the Script UI. But if you have an addon menu specified using `function onOpen(e)` and then call it while the sheet is active it works.